# binding settimeout on mouseleave with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I was building a slide-menu with javascript using classes and objects and a little bit of jquery as part of my efforts to learn javascript more deeply.
Everything went right until I wanted to bind a mouseleave to the initiator of my menu.
So here's my code block

```
 var el;
 function generate(obj){
  return function(){obj.slidein();}
  } 
 function slider(arg1,arg2){
 ...//Some junk
 el=this;
 for(i=0;i<this.nsubs;i++){ ...
 $("#"+this.id+i).bind('mouseleave',function(){setTimeout("generate(el)",500)});
  }
 ...
 }
```

Well, I get no error on firefox error console but somehow the slidein() function which I want to be attached to the mouseleave is not being called when mouse leaves the element in question.

Can Someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `el` having what?? and also in for loop write `( for var i=0;...`

Comment: @diEcho:
I've got no idea on what you mean! Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I sorted it out on my own, what I actually needed was a closure that returns a function with 'setTimeout(generate(ObjPassedToClosure))'

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a function rather than a string to setTimeout:

```
$("#"+this.id+i).bind('mouseleave', function() {
   setTimeout(function() { 
      generate(el); 
   }, 500)
});
```

Comment: (sorry for double comment I couldnt edit it within 5 mins, continuing: )executing:setTimeout(generate(el), 500); on firefox console, it works.
BTW, I also found out that  removing the " around the generate function in my above code block seems to work but only for the last element covered by the for loop!(but I want it to work for each element) Any help is still appreciated..